# What is the current way (mid October 2019) to include the implementation Compat dependency in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making my first Android app and following along with articles on Developer.Android .

My simple app needs to fire some notifications and I wanted to start simply by hard coding one notification in. When I follow the directions in this article (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification), I get errors when I paste in that dependency line to my build.gradle file. The error says that it's deprecated[image] (see image for error message).

What is the current way to add this dependency that will not cause an error message and get my notification to work?

Comment: I've tried to google this but don't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

...Let me google that for myself (sometimes I just need to articulate the question)

according to this article, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat, the new line to add to build.gradle is:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
```

and (drumroll) .... it doesn't show any errors!! :D

edit: this is not a good answer because now the build fails and sync fails.

edit again: i had an extra "}" ...build works

Comment: The correct (At this time) version is 1.1.0 of that appcompat dependency; this is in October 2019.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini do I need to include that detail when I add the line of code to my gradle file?

Comment: ...and, even if I do get the dependency right, things changed that make the code associated with the dependency in my activity.main file break ... I wish they would update the official article.

Comment: problem is now my sync fails... bummer

Comment: changing to androidx likely requires changing several other things to androidx... the easiest way to convert your project is in the refactor menu at the top of android studio select `Migrate to androidx...` and it will do the rest for you

Comment: Did you change the imports in your Java or Kotlin files? Did you modify your XML files to, for example <com.support.xxxxxx> into <androidx.xxxxx> versions? These are the kinds of things you ought to do when migrating. If it's a big project, trying the auto-migration may help. [take a look at the official Google guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). :)

Answer (score 0):

When your project depends on an artifact like `com.android.support.*`, you have a few choices:

1. If the dependency is transitive, or comes from another library, you can try to exclude it.

E.g.:

com.some.library:1.0 -> needs com.android.support.*

In most cases, whatever is needed from com.android.support, is usually available and backwards compatible in the corresponding androidx artifact. E.g.: a `com.android.support.fragment` should work the same (at the very least) than its androidx counterpart. (Unfortunately, this is not *always* the case).

The androidX migration should replace the support artifact with the corresponding androidx for you; see the enable jetifier thing in the [official android migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

You can still use your `com.some.library` but you're going to have to tell it to `exclude` the support library (so they don't clash):

e.g.:

```
    implementation ('com.some.library:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

This way, `some.library` will "find" its dependencies, but taken from your androidx artifacts.

2. Another thing you can do is let the migration do its thing and hope for the best. In most cases, all the migration does is identify where you have replaceable by androidx dependencies, and modify your XML files, Java/Kotlin imports, etc. to use the new ones. In some cases the migration tool may suggest issues or something, but I've only used it a couple of times in small-ish projects so the issues were very minor and in some cases false positives.

But in short, anywhere you have, say?

`<com.android.support.Fragment />`

You'd have to replace with 
`<androidx.Fragment />` (I can't remember the exact imports now, but you get the idea).

You also have to replace your Java or Kotlin imports to reference the new classes:

`import com.android.support.Fragment`

becomes

`import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` <-- this one is real, I remember it :)

The other thing the migration does, is to enable the "jetifier" and androidx project wide.

The Jetifier will look at your code and will "replace" the references for you, even after you've compiled your code (or maybe it does it during compilation, I don't remember) but the point is that if a library uses a support reference, it will get androidx-ified for you. The Jetifier was problematic when it first came out, but by now, I've had good success with it. So I suggest you try it.

My last advice (given that I had to perform this support->androidx migration in two medium sized projects) is to go slow, one reference at a time, and compiling and testing things as much as you can. And resist the temptation to update all libraries at once. It can lead to unexpected and hard to find problems that generate other problems that may not exist if you had solved the first one... in short: take it slow and analyze each error.

using `./gradlew app:dependencies` is also a good way to figure out where some problematic dependency is coming from.

Keep in mind that some of these issues may arise when you use proguard or minify, and not on "debug" builds (due to clash between the same classes in the classpath). The infamous "duplicate class found..." error, among others.

So always try to test, each change.

And last but not least, I suggest you do **not** skip versions in-between:

E.g.: If your project is targeting api 26 and you use build tools 26.x.x, do not try to jump to androidX (or try, but if you have problems, roll back).

Instead, migrate to Api 28 (for example) and support tools 28.0.3 (latest support version before androidx). Once you have all working fine up there, only then proceed to try the androidx artifacts.

Good luck!